# Microsoft WebForms ReportViewer cancel rendering

Tags: reportviewer, webforms

In my application I am using a ReportViewer. The application is webbased application and hence I used Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms (v 9.0.0.0) namespace and the reportviewer from that namespace. My problem is to stop rendering/cancel the report in a click of a button.

In Winforms the same mechanism can be done by CancelRendering method. Could anyone tell me how to stop the rendering of reportviewer / cancel the loading of report viewer in webforms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

reportViewer.Reset() done the trick!